# Android - Simple permissions - Why don't I need this permission?

Tags: android, permissions

I'm currently working images using

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
```

My permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I thought I needed a read storage permission to get the files from the gallery. Why can I access files from my Gallery without this permission?

If it helps, I'm using the **ACTION_SEND** intent filter to start the activity via a "Share" dialog.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, my application works perfectly. I thought I would need a special permission to read files from the SD card (such as images).  Is this not the case?

Comment: what exactly are you asking? If you can't access files from gallery then what's happening exactly? any exceptions or output?

Comment: There is no need of permission to read from SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes, I don't have this permission in my  Manifest, but the application works perfectly as expected. I am on a Galaxy S2